# Is it possible to generate a graph in nvd3.js using this data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have a small function that outputs the following:

```
[
    {
        "label": "A",
        "value": 101.23
    },
    {
        "label": "B",
        "value": 109.87
    },
    {
        "label": "C",
        "value": 107.34
    },
    {
        "label": "D",
        "value": 115.17
    },
    {
        "label": "E",
        "value": 119.61
    }
]
```

What I am trying and failing miserably at is generating a graph with that data. I'd like to generate a simple bar chart with nvd3, or with d3.

What I have is this:

```
var output = [];

Object.keys(input.Data).forEach(function(key){
    if(key.indexOf('mean') > -1){
    output.push({label: key,value: input.Data[key]});
    }
});

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
        .x(function (d) {return d.label})
        .y(function (d) {return d.value})


    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(output)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

I'm getting a TypeError: cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

I'm not familiar enough with nvd3, or d3 to track this down, but it could be related to a version mismatch. I'm using d3 v3.5.1 and nvd3 v1.8.3. Just a guess though.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The data MUST be in this format.

```
output = [{
  key: "",
  values: [{
    "label": "A",
    "value": 101.23
  }, {
    "label": "B",
    "value": 109.87
  }, {
    "label": "C",
    "value": 107.34
  }, {
    "label": "D",
    "value": 115.17
  }, {
    "label": "E",
    "value": 119.61
  }]
}]
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hVOCMATcm04bDmzq4t9S?p=preview)